# WPF MVVM formatted Text Binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I'm Using MVVM in WPF (.Net 3.5) and I need a control that supports formatted text, bold & italics, and I can bind to easily.
When I say easily I mean something like Text ="{Binding FormattedText}" and that's it.
RichTextBox blows for binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [A Bindable WPF RichTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/BindableWPFRichTextBox.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `HtmlToXamlConverter` as in here [HTML Textblock](http://jacob4u2.blogspot.com/2009/09/bind-html-to-textblock-with-html-to.html) and here [Rich textblock](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2010/09/09/A-Rich-HTML-TextBlock-for-WPF.aspx)